# Sentence Auto-Complete with Java

Tags: java, autocomplete, sentence

Lets say I have about 1000 sentences that I want to offer as suggestions when user is typing into a field.

I was thinking about running `lucene in memory search` and then feeding the results into the `suggestions set`.

The `trigger` for running the searches would be `space char` and `exit from the input field`.

I intend to use  this with `GWT` so the client with be just getting the results from server.

I don't want to do what google is doing; where they complete each word and than make suggestions on each set of keywords. I just want to check the keywords and make suggestions based on that. Sort of like when I'm typing the title for the question here on stackoverflow.

#### Did anyone do something like this before? Is there already library I could use?

Comment: I'd want to clarify that you don't mean [SuggestBox](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SuggestBox.html) behavior instead the suggestions are presented in a distinct UI element? I could see how you might define an SuggestOracle that provides sentences and tweak the suggest box to suggest only when the last change was a space char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've only got 1000 sentences, you probably don't need a powerful indexer like lucene. I'm not sure whether you want to do "complete the sentence" suggestions or "suggest other queries that have the same keywords" suggestions. Here are solutions to both:

Assuming that you want to complete the sentence input by the user, then you could put all of your strings into a [`SortedSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html), and use the `tailSet` method to get a list of strings that are "greater" than the input string (since the [string comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) considers a longer string `A` that starts with string `B` to be "greater" than `B`). Then, iterate over the top few entries of the set returned by `tailSet` to create a set of strings where the first `inputString.length()` characters match the input string. You can stop iterating as soon as the first `inputString.length()` characters don't match the input string.

If you want to do keyword suggestions instead of "complete the sentence" suggestions, then the overhead depends on how long your sentences are, and how many unique words there are in the sentences. If this set is small enough, you'll be able to get away with a `HashMap<String,Set<String>>`, where you mapped keywords to the sentences that contained them. Then you could handle multiword queries by intersecting the sets.

In both cases, I'd probably convert all strings to lower case first (assuming that's appropriate in your application). I don't think either solution would scale to hundreds of thousands of suggestions either. Do either of those do what you want? Happy to provide code if you'd like it.

Answer (score 2):

I was working on a similar solution. This paper titled [Effective Phrase Prediction](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1325879) was quite helpful for me . You will have to prioritize the suggestions as well

Comment: does this have java implementation, or you can suggest some open source